# How to create a new user in aspnetdb, when using asp:login control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, login-control, aspnetdb

I need to add the capability to create a user in an app built using the `asp:Login control`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Have you taken a look at the [Web Site Administration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0.aspx)?

> To access the Web Site Administration
>   Tool, on the **Website** menu, click
>   **ASP.Net Configuration**.